# Highcharts - series is invisible because clippath is set incorrectly

Tags: highcharts, invisible

The following issue happens in Firefox 20.0.1 and IE10, but works in Chrome.

When I test a highchart plot in Firefox 20.0.1 or IE10, the chart series is invisible. After looking into the chart html, I found the clipPath in the SVG is not set correctly.

There are 4 "clipPath" defined in the "defs" section, as follows:

```
`
<defs>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
        <rect height="110" width="9999" y="0" x="0" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-2">
        <rect height="0" width="1228" y="0" x="0" fill="none"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-14">
        <rect height="0" width="0" y="0" x="0" fill="none"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="highcharts-15">
        <rect height="110" width="99" y="-40" x="-99" fill="none" ry="0" rx="0"></rect>
    </clipPath>
</defs>
```

`

In the "highcharts-series" "g" tag, it uses "clip-path="url(#highcharts-14)"". Which causes the chart series invisible. If I manually change the clip-path to url(#highcharts-2), chart shows up.

Since I didn't set any clipPath related options in the highchart, why the "highcharts-14" and "highcharts-15" get defined and used? How to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: I use the most recent HighCharts 3.0.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsfiddle, please.

Comment: Are you using any HighCharts plugins? I've come across an issue with https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events which I've logged here: https://github.com/blacklabel/custom_events/issues/50